# What is layer freezing in transfer learning?

Tags: transfer-learning

Transfer learning consists of taking features learned on one problem and leveraging them on a new, similar problem.

In the Transfer Learning, we take layers from a previously trained model and freeze them.

**Why is this layer freezing required and what are the effects of layer freezing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why is this layer freezing required?**

It's not.

**What are the effects of layer freezing?**
The consequences are:

(1) Should be *faster* to train (the gradient will have far less components)

(2) Should require *less* data to train on

If you do unfreeze the weights, I'd think your performance would be better because you are adjusting (i.e., fine-tuning) the parameters to your specific problem at hand. I am not sure what the marginal improvements are in practice, as I have not experiemented much with fine-tuning (like are the improvements typically a 0.01% reduction in error rate? Not sure.)

Answer (score 0):

Layer freezing means that the layer weights of the trained model do not change when reused on a subsequent downstream mission, they remain frozen. Basically, when backpropagation is performed during training, these layer weights aren't compromised.