# Does layer freezing offer other benefits other than to reduce computational time in gradient descent?

Tags: deep-learning, training, transfer-learning, fine-tuning

In Deep Learning and Transfer Learning, does layer freezing offer other benefits other than to reduce computational time in gradient descent?

Assuming I train a neural network on task A to derive weights $W_{A}$, set these as initial weights and train on another task B (without layer freezing), does it still count as transfer learning?

In summary, how essential is layer freezing in transfer learning?

Comment: Welcome to this SE :) Be sure to look around on the SE for all the questions that others have posted. The following describes some of the things you are asking for: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/22963/what-is-layer-freezing-in-transfer-learning

Answer (score 1):

from your post I assume you are having three sub-questions and I will answer them one by one.

- For the 1st question, yes, layer freezing reduces the computational cost a lot and also helps the model to keep the many patterns it has learned to recognize things better, c negative to positive samples easier and avoid overfitting if it was trained on a bigger dataset. Said like having a model trained on COCO but now we only want a person detection model, without freezing weights, our model may not generalize as well as it was before due to backprops now just focusing on one class.
- The second one, yes! Without freezing but still using pretrained model as initial weights is also counted as transfer learning
- Finally, in summary, layer freezing is a very essential trick to have a good model, especially if you want it to work well in the open-world dataset and generalize for as many domains as possible, time-saving and easier for fine-tuning as we now just have to train the final downstream task layers.
  Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 1):

Both are transfer learning approaches, which this Pytorch tutorial explains very well:

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html

> In practice, very few people train an entire Convolutional Network
> from scratch (with random initialization), because it is relatively
> rare to have a dataset of sufficient size. Instead, it is common to
> pretrain a ConvNet on a very large dataset (e.g. ImageNet, which
> contains 1.2 million images with 1000 categories), and then use the
> ConvNet either as an initialization or a fixed feature extractor for
> the task of interest.
>
> These two major transfer learning scenarios look as follows:
>
> **Finetuning the convnet**: Instead of random initialization, we
> initialize the network with a pretrained network, like the one that is
> trained on imagenet 1000 dataset. Rest of the training looks as usual.
>
> **ConvNet as fixed feature extractor**: Here, we will freeze the weights
> for all of the network except that of the final fully connected layer.
> This last fully connected layer is replaced with a new one with random
> weights and only this layer is trained.

In summary layer freezing is faster, but it is less accurate (after enough training) than finetuning.